# Does play2 framework uses ehcache wrapper on avaje ebeans bean cache?

Tags: javabeans, playframework-2.0, ebean

Does play2 framework uses ehcache wrapper on avaje ebeans bean cache ?

It seems to me that ehcache have to be more efficient, and it's not hard to implement wrapper around standart bean cache. But I don't know how play2 working with the bean cache itself.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Ebean/Play integration](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/db/ebean/EbeanPlugin.java), it does not seem that Play set any L2 cache for Ebean.

So Ebean must be using its default cache mechanism (`com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.cache.DefaultServerCache`).